# Images not found when doing a production build with JHipster

Tags: jhipster, gulp-imagemin

When I am trying to deploy my application in my prod the WAR do not
have the images directory so i get my application deploy without any
images.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Which version of JHipster? Where is located the source folder of your images?

Comment: Hi, i used the last version of jhipster ( "jhipsterVersion": "3.0.0")..

Comment: 3.1.0 is last version, please try upgrading

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the cause of the problem is "gulp-imagemin", as a workaround remove this line:

```
.pipe(imagemin({optimizationLevel: 5, progressive: true, interlaced: true}))
```

from: gulpfile.js

Answer (score 1):

Your images must be in `src/main/webapp/content/images` to get minified and copied by gulp to `target/www/content/images` and then be copied at the root of you war in `content/images` by maven or gradle.

Comment: My images are in the folder you mention.. src/main/webapp/content/images.. I have just css folder minified and not the other

Comment: Look at the output of your build, there must be something about your images.

Comment: please i don't understand what you mean by "output of your build"

Comment: redirect the output of your build to a file and then take time to review it in a text editor: `mvn -Pprod package > build.txt`

Comment: Still have the same problem event with a new project generated without modifications?

Comment: Still have the same problem event with a new project generated without modifications... The gulp sames to work well. Is just the  "gulp-imagemin:Minified 0 images" could not work don't know why

Comment: Are you using node LTS version as recommended in our doc? Have you tried to upgrade to 3.1.0 as I told you earlier?

Comment: yes i'm using the last node and i have upgrated to 3.1.0, but still not haven't the image folder

Comment: in my target folder, i have: the 2 .war and all the test and classes folders . a folder www in which i can fine the image folder in "content" but no images in it.  But in the .war (s) no folder "images" in content...

Comment: You upgraded jhipster and ran 'yo jhipster' again in your project, right?

Comment: sorry i was not able to answer, this last few days..
yes i have upgrated and ran yo jhipster again in my project..
i  have created a new project to test the purpose but still the same prob

Comment: this could be a gulp-imagemin problem, doesn't minified my images from content/images folder.. How to i fix this please

Comment: What does print 'node -v', which OS are you running?

Comment: i use windows 7... my "node -v" is  5.9.1

Comment: So you're not using node LTS version which is what we recommend in doc. I'd recommend you downgrade to node LTS, delete your project's `node_modules` folder and re-run `npm install` in your project

Comment: i have done what you ask me to do, but still the same problem.. can have my images in the image folder

Comment: Then sorry I can't help you unless you share your code.

Answer (score 0):

If gulp-imagemin says it minified 0 images, it's often due to missing binaries needed in these node modules:

- optipng
- jpegtran
- gifsicle

If you look eg. into `node_modules/optipng-bin`, you'll see that the `optipng` binary is missing (should be in a `vendor` subfolder).

They are not compiled during npm install, and it's completely silent :)

Installing the `zlib1g-dev` package fixed the issue on a fresh Debian 9 system.

> I had to install build-base and zlib-dev
>   https://github.com/imagemin/optipng-bin/issues/84

Generally speaking, you need several build tools on your system to build a JHipster prod package (make, g++ for scss, etc.).