# gulp-imagemin: Minified 0 images?

Tags: gulp, jhipster, gulp-imagemin

Hi in my project i am using gulp-imagemin to minifi my images form my def to my prod application. This happen to no work.. 
i get the folders without the images in it..

This is what is been done:

### gulp.task('images', function () {

```
return gulp.src(config.app + 'content/images/**')
    .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
    .pipe(changed(config.dist + 'content/images'))
    .pipe(imagemin({optimizationLevel: 5, progressive: true, interlaced: true}))
    .pipe(rev())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist + 'content/images'))
    .pipe(rev.manifest(config.revManifest, {
        base: config.dist,
        merge: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
```

});

what's going wrong??

Comment: Could you provide details concerning your environment? OS, Node version, etc. I have the same problem when running with Jenkins on CentOS, but the same works fine locally on Mac OS X. Could be related to dependencies or versions... as it fails silently, even when adding verbose: true.

Comment: Looks like you have 2 `gulp.dest`s going, also, what is the path in your `config.app` variable? Additionally what is `rev()` doing?

Comment: Check my answer to the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55765109/1458562

Answer (score 1):

I also face same issue but solved by using absolute path in src and in dist.

```
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
gulp.task('imagemin-uploads', function () {
    return gulp.src('F:/laragon/www/fashion/wp-content/uploads/**/*')
        .pipe(imagemin([
        imagemin.gifsicle({interlaced: true}),
        imagemin.jpegtran({progressive: true}),
        imagemin.optipng(),
        imagemin.svgo([{removeViewBox: false}, {minifyStyles: false}])
        ], {verbose: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('F:/laragon/www/fashion/wp-content/themes/uploads/'))
});
```